# Q: CQN dbms_cq_notification.cq_notification_queryid

Tags: oracle

What's "dbms_cq_notification.cq_notification_queryid" doing on this SELECT? I'm just learning CQN. I also believe mgr_id is not being used or is it?

```
DECLARE
  reginfo    cq_notification$_reg_info;
  mgr_id     NUMBER;
  dept_id    NUMBER;
  v_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  regid      NUMBER;
  qosflags   NUMBER;  

BEGIN
  qosflags := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_QUERY + DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS;
  reginfo  := cq_notification$_reg_info('chnf_callback', qosflags,0, 0, 0);
  regid    := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.NEW_REG_START(reginfo);

  OPEN v_cursor FOR 
    SELECT DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.CQ_NOTIFICATION_QUERYID, 
           manager_id
    FROM HR.employees
    WHERE employee_id = 7902;
  CLOSE v_cursor;

  OPEN v_cursor for
    SELECT DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.CQ_NOTIFICATION_QUERYID, 
           department_id
    FROM HR.departments
    WHERE department_name = 'IT';
  CLOSE v_cursor;

  DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.REG_END;
END;
```

I took it from here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_cqnotif.htm#ARPLS65637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you register "n" queries.

An hour later your application is going to be notified that the results from a registered query has changed.  Which query is it ?  How do you know ?  That is what the ID is for.  Your notification client can be informed which query caused the notification.  If you don't care which query initiated the event, you do not need it.